# Examples of WordPress being used as a CMS in a B2B market (Business-to-Business)

Tags: wiki

Can anyone provide me with some links to high profile sites that are using using WordPress as their CMS as a B2B marketing site?

The reason why I am asking is that I'm putting together a proposal document and would like to give some examples of other B2B sites that are using WordPress as their whole website and not just their blog.

I've been looking on the [WordPress Showcase](http://wordpress.org/showcase/) but cannot find any high profile B2B websites. There are a fair amount of high profile sites but those sites don't use WordPress as their main corporate site. Rather they use WordPress as a micro site or side blog.

Examples of high profile B2B sites for me would be:

- [Bloomberg](http://www.bloomberg.com/)
- [KPMG](http://www.kpmg.com/uk/en/pages/default.aspx)
- [Ernst & Young](http://www.ey.com/UK/en/home)

Do you know of any high profile B2B sites using WordPress as their main site?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://wpmu.org/wordpress-drupal-and-open-source-dominate-2012-presidential-campaign-websites/) article recently profiled political sites for the 2012 US Presidential race that use Open Source CMS. The WordPress ones featured where http://www.ronpaul2012.com/ and http://www.michelebachmann.com/. I would say that these are high profile.